# mysql get next row ordered by multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database, range, row

I have a database with products. When I selected a product I want to get the next product in my database.

For Example:
I have the product with ID 188 and I want to get the next product with ID 167.

Database:

```
SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY title ASC, description ASC
+----+----------------------+----------------------+
| id | title                | description          |
+----+----------------------+----------------------+
|111 | Adjusterhouse        | Finetuning           |
+----+----------------------+----------------------+
|188 | Adjustment housing   | Height               |
+----+----------------------+----------------------+
|167 | Adjustment housing   | Oilpressure          |
+----+----------------------+----------------------+
|105 | Adjustment housing   | Suspension           |
+----+----------------------+----------------------+
|102 | Adjustment nut L+R.  | Packaging machinery  |
+----+----------------------+----------------------+
```

But if I use the following SQL Statement I get the product with the ID 102 instead of 167.

```
SELECT * FROM product 
WHERE title > ? AND (title > ? OR description > ?) 
ORDER BY title ASC, description ASC LIMIT 1
```

Can someone help me with this SQL statement?

Comment: Is it possible to have duplicate titles and descriptions?

Comment: +1. This is the right approach. Just change that first **greater than** comparison to be **greater than or equal to**. You'll be good as long as the `(title,description)` is unique. (We're assuming here obviously that the values supplied for the placeholders are the values from the last fetched (currently displayed) row. If it's not unique, we'd need to introduce another column to make it unique, looks like `id` would be an ideal candidate. Given your data, it's not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the right approach. Only one small change is required, changing that first comparison to be "*greater than* ***or equal to***" instead of just "*greater than*".

As long as the `(title,description)` tuple is unique, that will work just fine. This is the pattern you want:

```
WHERE ( title >= ? )
  AND ( title > ? OR description > ? )
```

(The only change there is that you need a "`title`**`>=`**" comparison as the first condition in the `WHERE`. Everything else you have is fine.

---

**If the `(title,description)` tuple is not guaranteed to be unique...**

we'd need to add additional column to the ordering. The `id` column looks like an ideal candidate. That gets a little more complicated, but the pattern is similar...

```
WHERE ( title >= ? )
  AND ( title > ? OR 
                     (

                           ( description >= ? )
                       AND ( description > ? OR id > ? )

                     )
      )

 ORDER BY title ASC, description ASC, id ASC
```

Note that we've nested the same pattern;  the pattern used for `description` and `id` is the same as we used for `title` and `description`.

The outer part is still the same pattern, but now it's on `title` and instead of just plain `description`, we've got the condition that works on the `(description,id)` tuple.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now like this:
SELECT * FROM product WHERE title >= ? AND (title > ? OR (( description >= ? ) AND ( description > ? OR id > ? ))) ORDER BY title ASC, description ASC, id, ASC LIMIT 1

And I think it works well, thanks.

Comment: @rraayy: that where clause looks right to me. (Have to supply the `title` value twice, the `description` value twice, and the `id` value once. That same pattern could be extended to use a fourth column. If you wanted to order by "color" or "unit price" or something. Including that primary key value (i'm assuming id is the primary key) as the very last ensures that the ordering is deterministic, and no two rows will have the exact same values in the `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0):

Your sorting on title with a `>`.  Assuming you've got record 188, the title is `Adjustment housing` If you look you'll set the first record with a `title < 'Adjustment housing'` is in fact record 102.

Change it to be :

```
SELECT * FROM product 
 WHERE title >= ? AND description >= ? AND id != ? 
 ORDER BY title ASC, description ASC, id ASC LIMIT 1
```

Where the second `?` is replaced with the id 188 in your prepared statment parameter binding

Comment: After row id=167 is returned, a subsequent execution is going to return row  id=188 again. And then id=167. And then id=188. This algo will get stuck at those two rows. You are right that we'd would need to introduce `id` into the ordering, if we aren't guaranteed that the `(title,description)` tuple isn't unique.

Comment: @spencer7593 forgot to keep description in the clause

Comment: @spencer7593 of course with Duplicate descriptions you'll get the same issue

Answer (score -1):

Your use case isn't well defined, but one way to accomplish this would be via the `limit` clause.

So, the following query would return the first row:

```
SELECT *
FROM product
ORDER BY title ASC, description ASC LIMIT 0, 1
```

would return *118,Adjusterhouse,Finetuning*.

You could then use:

```
SELECT *
FROM product
ORDER BY title ASC, description ASC LIMIT 1, 1
```

to return *111,Adjustment housing,Height*.

You'd need to use `SELECT (COUNT(1) - 1) as max_offset FROM product` to know how far to "offset" your data. The maximum offset would always be number of rows, minus 1. In your sample data, the largest offset would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM product
ORDER BY title ASC, description ASC LIMIT 4, 1
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This approach (using an offset) can get *very* expensive with large sets, when you are up into offsets of thousands of rows. The OP approach can be much more efficient, in terms of quickly skipping over the rows that aren't needed.

Comment: Right. Like I said, the use case wasn't well defined. I obviously don't have the skillset to answer this question in full. However, what is being placed in the '?' for his query? Is it the previous "title" and "description?"

Comment: yes, that's a good question. I assumed that the values supplied for the placeholders was for the previously fetched (currently displayed) row. Beyond the performance issue with large sets, this approach doesn't handle rows being inserted below the current row. What was row 4 on the previous query can be row 5 on the next query, if a row with a lower `title` is inserted in the interim, making the next fetch return the same row. And removal of lower title rows can result in rows being "skipped".

Comment: Agreed. I'll say it just once more to clarify that the use case wasn't well defined. I made two assumptions: 1) this product table isn't added to with great frequency and 2) this product table isn't more than a few thousands of rows.